# Sinatra fails to answer to a very basic GET request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-1.9

I have the following Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra', '1.3.2'
gem 'json', '1.6.4'
```

And the following Sinatra application:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

get '/ze/api/session.json' do
  content_type :json
  { :name => 'name' }
end
```

And when I make a basic request like this one:

```
curl localhost:4567/ze/api/session.json
```

I get this:

```
[2012-01-13 17:30:36] ERROR TypeError: can't convert Array into String
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@office-drop-sync/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:72:in `block in service'
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@office-drop-sync/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `each'
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@office-drop-sync/gems/rack-1.4.0/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:71:in `service'
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/mauricio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
localhost - - [13/Jan/2012:17:30:36 BRT] "GET /ze/api/session.json HTTP/1.1" 500 311
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM in a Lion Mac.

Comment: Perhaps an unhelpful comment, but your code is solid, works fine here on Ubuntu 10.10  Are you starting the app by doing `ruby app.rb`?

Comment: @Gazler the error is coming from the webrick handler. Try adding `set :server, 'webrick'` and you should be able to reproduce it. It seems the other handlers (thin?) are more forgiving here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to return a hash from the route, but a hash isn't [something you can return here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Return%20Values).

Simply use `.to_json` to turn the hash into a json string which you can then return (you've required json, but aren't using it yet):

```
get '/ze/api/session.json' do
  content_type :json
  { :name => 'name' }.to_json
end
```

Comment: That's it, thanks, the tutorial I followed did not mention the to_json call.